# Selecting based on column names from another select (EVAL?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, eval

I have 2 tables, one with a list of column names that need counts, and one with the data to be counted

```
Table A
ProgramId  ColumnName
1          Country
1          Gender
2          AgeRange
2          Region

Table B
ProgramId  Country  Gender  AgeRange  Region
1          USA      M       18-25     Midwest
1          USA      F       <18       Northeast
1          MEX      M       <18       South
2          USA      M       18-25     Midwest
2          USA      M       26-35     Midwest
```

Given a a specific ProgramId, I need a list of each column from table A joined with each value and count from table B

Example output needed (parameters: @ProgramId = 1)

```
ColumnName  ColumnValue  ValueCount
Country     USA          2
Country     MEX          1
Gender      M            2
Gender      F            1
```

From what I've been able to find googling, I will need some sort of dynamic statement. This is fine by me, since the only people with access to table A will be internal developers.

Comment: You just need to create a dynamic SQL clause based on the input and execute it using sp_executesql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebdfe/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (ProgramId INT, ColumnName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES
(1          ,'Country'),
(1          ,'Gender'),
(2          ,'AgeRange'),
(2          ,'Region')


CREATE TABLE TableB (ProgramId VARCHAR(20), Country VARCHAR(20), 
      Gender VARCHAR(20), AgeRange VARCHAR(20), Region VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES
('1'          ,'USA'      ,'M'       ,'18-25'     ,'Midwest'),
('1'          ,'USA'      ,'F'       ,'<18'       ,'Northeast'),
('1'          ,'MEX'      ,'M'       ,'<18'       ,'South'),
('2'          ,'USA'      ,'M'       ,'18-25'     ,'Midwest'),
('2'          ,'USA'      ,'M'       ,'26-35'     ,'Midwest')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;With x AS 
(
Select * 
From TableB 
      UNPIVOT(ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (Gender, Country))up
)
Select x.ColumnName
      ,x.ColumnValue
      ,COUNT(x.ColumnValue) ValueCount
From x 
inner join TableA a ON x.ColumnName = a.ColumnName
WHERE x.ProgramId = 1   --<-- or maybe the parameter @ProgramId
GROUP BY x.ColumnName,x.ColumnValue
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebdfe/1/0)**:

```
| ColumnName | ColumnValue | ValueCount |
|------------|-------------|------------|
|    Country |         MEX |          1 |
|    Country |         USA |          2 |
|     Gender |           F |          1 |
|     Gender |           M |          2 |
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to see

Comment: Just finished, the only change I had to make was to build a varchar as a comma delimited list from my columns from TableA and wrap the whole thing in a EXEC, replacing Gender, Country with my built variable

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to generate the code.  The second is to run it.

Assuming your columns have no special names or strange characters:

```
select @sql = ('select ' + cols +
               ', count(*) as ValueCount from b group by ' + cols
              )
from (select stuff((select ', ' + a.ColumnName
                    from a
                    where programid = @programid
                    for xml path ('')
                   ), 1, 2, ''
                  ) as cols
     ) x;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```